# GLSurfaceView: Do I need to to call onPause/onResume?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using a GLSurfaceView (sdk version 7) in RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY. The documentation says I need to call onPause/onResume, but it works fine without it, so I am wondering. Is it required? What can happen if I don't?

Comment: does it work fine even when you leave the application and return? I've always needed to implement onPause and onResume in order to keep the GlSurfaceView working after leaving and returning to application.

Comment: Yes, that it, it works fine under all conditions: home screen-return, switch screen off-unlock-return, losing focus then return. It has been running fine for a couple of weeks and I just happened to read the onPause stuff in the documentation, so I'm wondering.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The implementation of GLSurfaceView's onPause looks like this:

```
/**
 * Inform the view that the activity is paused. The owner of this view must
 * call this method when the activity is paused. Calling this method will
 * pause the rendering thread.
 * Must not be called before a renderer has been set.
 */
public void onPause() {
    mGLThread.onPause();
}
```

You can see (and the documentation states) that it pauses the rendering thread. This causes an internal call in the GLThread to stopEglLocked which looks like this:

```
 private void stopEglLocked() {
        if (mHaveEgl) {
            mHaveEgl = false;
            mEglHelper.destroySurface();
            mEglHelper.finish();
            sGLThreadManager.releaseEglSurface(this);
        }
 }
```

So you can see it destroys the surface which is an expensive system resource, and causes thread to wait(), which also saves system resources, cpu, baterry, etc.

So, calling GLSurfaceView's onPause and onResume is definitely required.